# Role for reading webjobs logs in Azure/Kudu

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I am trying to give a user access to my webjobs logs in Azure and/or Kudu for a specific application. What I am want to achieve is to give the user reading rights so that she can read the status of the webjobs and the logs created. And she should be able to do that through Azure portal or through Kudu. Is this possible using *Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)* and using the predefined roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could try to assign the user with website contributor role in the new Azure Portal to meet your requirement. You could follow [role-based-access-control-configure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) for getting started with RBAC. Also, you could refer to this official [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/01/07/managing-user-access-to-specific-sites-in-the-azure-portal/) about managing user access to the specific web app for a good understanding of it.

Comment: Thanks. I added the website contributor role and it is good enough for this purpose.

Comment: I think this doesn't make sense, why i need to add user to the contributor list to read the logs!