# Permission to view Azure webjobs logs

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-webjobs

I would like to give read access to multiple colleagues to read Azure webjobs logs.

[Azure WebJobs logs button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbah1.png)

If you click on the button in the logs column, a new webpage opens that looks something like this: `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`

Currently, colleagues have read access to the entire RG, which includes the webapp.

Information: "You only have read access to this web app, some controls may be disabled"
Problem: Colleagues cannot click on the icon under the logs column.

I have tried to give the following privileges, but these privileges provide too powerful a role:

- Website Contributor
- Contributor
- Owner

I want them to be able to read the logs only, but not to have any other rights.
Or can you suggest a better alternative?

If the information is relevant for permissions, different app service plans are currently used.
There is basic, standard, premium v2 and v3.

I also saw this post, but I consider this permission to be too much.
[Role for reading webjobs logs in Azure/Kudu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158221/role-for-reading-webjobs-logs-in-azure-kudu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply a specific role to your user, You need to create a custom role like below:-

***Visit your Subscription > Access control  (IAM) > Add custom role > In Basics tab add Custom role name Start from scratch > In permissions > Select the specific role for your webjob whether continous or triggered webjob and web app to get the logs:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In addition in order to retrieve `https://webapp0980.scm.azurewebsites.net` > Logs, You cannot access the Kudu tool in UI as the support for its access was declined, According to this [**MS Forum**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a837bba-081d-4f33-8127-b6beda37df0c/advanced-tools-kudu-scm-not-authorized?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

> As mentioned in the feedback link [**read-only role for Kudu**](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/0a79572f-c925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c)  the ask for read only role for Kudu has been declined, as access to Kudu intrinsically requires Contributor access.

You can raise a new feature request for a custom Kudu based role.

[image]

***But you can Add the roles below to get the Web app logs with Azure CLI via command even without the UI access:-***

[image]

[image]

You can select assignable scope to your Web App directly or at subscription level like below:-

[image]

***Create the role and assign it to the user and run the command to download the logs:-***

```bash
az webapp log download --name webapp0980 --resource-group siliconrg54
```

**Output:-**

[image]